# Ruby on Rails - how to integrate ckeditor plugins with rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-6

So, I'm using the ckeditor gem with rails 6;

javascript/packs/application.js:

```
require("packs/ckeditor/config")
```

javascript/packs/ckeditor/config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  config.extraPlugins = 'eqneditor,imageresizerowandcolumn,balloontoolbar,balloonpanel';
  // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
  // config.language = 'fr';
  // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
  config.resize_enabled = true;
  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures?";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  config.allowedContent = true;
  config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form';

};
```

views:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag Ckeditor.cdn_url%>
<%= cktext_area :notes, ckeditor: {toolbar: 'Full'}%>
```

The editor loads properly but I do not see any of the plugins I configured in ckeditor's config.js

Comment: What's the console log? I think ckeditor cdn loaded after configuration run.

Comment: Have you finally solved your issue. I'm facin g the same issue with the wordcount plugin in ckeditor? Any help will be appreciated...